# Help with storing object keys in a session using JDO/App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, jdo

I'm new to JDO/App Engine and looking for some help with storing keys of objects in my current session. I've created the following class and would like to access this key in another class?

```
@PersistenceCapable(identityType = IdentityType.APPLICATION )
```

public class Register {

```
@PrimaryKey
@Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY, mappedBy = "Game")
private Key userkey;

@Persistent
private String userName;

@Persistent
private String firstName;

@Persistent
private String age;

public Register(String userName, String firstName, String age) {
    this.userName = userName;
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.age = age;
}
```

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding your question...

Comment: What is "mappedBy" on a PK field of Key type trying to achieve? mappedBY is to link bidirectional relations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a `public Key getKey() { return key; }` method that external functions can call for access to the Key.  It's just a normal Java object.